# Cant get google recaptcha v2 to prevent form submission

Tags: php, jquery, html, captcha

So I can successfully get the captcha to validate, using the following code.

```
  </p>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
echo verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

}

function verify($response) {
$ip = $_SERVER['blank']; //server Ip
$key="secretkey"; // Secret key

//Build up the url
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$full_url = $url.'?secret='.$key.'&response='.$response.'&remoteip='.$ip;

//Get the response back decode the json
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($full_url));
//Return true or false, based on users input
if(isset($data->success) && $data->success == true) {
return True;
}
return False;
}
?>
<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 function verify(){
 var serializedValues = jQuery("#infoForm").serialize();
 jQuery.ajax({ type: 'POST',url:"verify.php",data: serializedValues,success:function(result){
 if(result){
 $('#show').html('Your Form Successfully Submitted');
 $('.formwrap').hide(result);
 return true;
 }
 }});
 $('#show').html('Please Enter Valid Captcha');
 return false;
}
 var onloadCallback = function() {
 grecaptcha.render('captcha_ele', {
 'sitekey' : 'Enter Your Site Key Here', // Site key
 });
 };
 </script>
```

However, when I click submit, regardless of what the captcha says, form will still submit. My email form process is as follows...

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

$("#blank").submit(function() {
    $.post('assets/php/email-process.php', {name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), message: $('#message').val(), myFormSubmitted: 'yes'}, 
    function(data) {
        $("#formResponse").html(data).fadeIn('100');
        $('#name, #email, #message').val(''); /* Clear the inputs */
    }, 'text');
    return false;
});
```

```html
<?php
if ($_POST['leaveblank'] != '' or $_POST['dontchange'] != 'http://') {
   // display message that the form submission was rejected
}
else {
   // accept form submission
$to = 'info@blank'; // Replace with your email  
    $subject = 'Message from website visitor'; // Replace with your $subject
    $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];    

    $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
               'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
               'Subject: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" .
               'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
    if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
    {
        mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
    echo 'Thank you for your Email. We will get in touch with you very soon.';

}


?>
```

Answer (score 43):

I use this which works for me. Put a js function in your form submit to validate the re-captcha:

```
<form action="/sign-visitors-log/" method="post" id="VisitorsLogForm" onsubmit="return validateRecaptcha();">
```

Then some js to stop the form submit if the user didn't tick the check box:

```
function validateRecaptcha() {
    var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if (response.length === 0) {
        alert("not validated");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("validated");
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can swap out the alerts for toast or as you are doing some elements on the page.

HTH

Comment: Nice, quick simple, and needed. Kept finding examples that are more after the submission.

Comment: Then you ask your bot to remove the inline onsubmit method and Bim badabum your captcha is doomed

Comment: That's why you also need an anti forgery token. But that's an answer to a different question.

Comment: In my case this was just a UX issue. I just needed a simple way to display a message to a real user without submitting the form. I actually used the example below from @Richard as it seems a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

In a separate js file (at least: no inline call to a function), you have to check if the captcha can validate. Like so:

```
  jquery('form').on('submit',function(e){

      if(grecaptcha.getResponse() === "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Error: \n please validate the Captcha test');
     }

  });
```

You don't have to check if the test passive as true, you have already prevented the form to be sent with this method.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler model that does the job

```js
document.querySelector(".form").addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{
    const response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if (response.length === 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please verify that you are human!");
    }
})
```

```html
<!--reCAPTCHA v2 -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<form action="/" method="POST" class"form">
<!--Please register as a developer and add "your_site_key" you will find it on https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create-->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
</form>
```